# php - discriminate between array types

Tags: php, arrays, types

I have 3 arrays:

```
$a = array('a',array('b','c'),'d'); (Type 1)

$b = array(array(1,2),3); (Type 2)

$c = array('e'=>'f', 'g'=>'h'); (Type 3)
```

I need to recognize these 3 types of array in a function in order to treat them differently.

```
if(Type 1)
{
   Do A;
}
elseif(Type 2)
{
   Do B;
}
elseiF(Type 3)
{
   Do C;
}
```

// Edit

I need to know that:

type 1: first item is a string value;

type 2: first item is an array;

type 3: is not a multidimentional array.

How could I deal with this?

Comment: Your question seems a little unclear to me. Can you explain a little more. Or can you post a sample output

Comment: What do you mean by: `I need to recognize these 3 types of array` ?

Comment: So what are these three different array types? 2 nested arrays, both enumerated; one associative array? Can you explain the differences?

Comment: I just add a little bit more details. Is this good enough?

Comment: You can identify a non-nested array by using `count()` with and without the COUNT_RECURSIVE flag, and testing if the results are different; otherwise `is_numeric($array[0])`

Comment: I still can't check if the first item is an array or not with count method.

Comment: `is_array()` will tell you if any variable is an array or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with my function, I've tested a few times and it seems to work ok.

I tried to optimize it so it don't waste resources if the array is big.

```
$a = array('a',array('b','c'),'d');
$b = array(array(1,2),3);
$c = array('e'=>'f', 'g'=>'h');
```

---

```
function arrayCheck($array){
    if(!is_array($array)) return null;
    $first = reset($array);
    if(is_array($first)) return 2;
    foreach($array as $v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            $is_multi = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!isset($is_multi)) return 3;
    if(is_string($first)) return 1;
}
```

---

```
var_dump(arrayCheck($a)); // returns 1
var_dump(arrayCheck($b)); // returns 2
var_dump(arrayCheck($c)); // returns 3
```

Answer (score 0):

DO one trick for this

```
$arr = array('a',array('b','c'),'d');
$join = join(',',$arr);

echo $join;
```

this will out put

a,Array,d

parsing above string you can find

type 1: first item is a string value;

type 2: first item is an array;

type 3: is not a multidimentional array.

I guess this will work

Answer (score 0):

```
function getArrayType($myArray=null) {
    if(!is_array($myArray))
        return false;
    if (count($myArray) == count($myArray, COUNT_RECURSIVE))
        return 'type 3';
    while (is_array($myArray[0])) {
        $myArray[0] = array_pop($myArray);
    }
    if (is_numeric($myArray[0]))
        return 'type 2';
    return 'type 1';
}
```

Comment: type 1 was supposed to check for string values, not numeric I think. Maybe I didn't understand your code correctly. I like your way to check if it's a multidimensional array, but wouldn't it be overkill if the array were big enough ?

Comment: In fact, your code is returning type 2, 1, 3; instead of 1, 2, 3; with the given arrays. Also, you missed the brace declaring the function :P. Aaaand, the first 'if' is checking for `$myVar` ( which doesn't exist ) instead of `$myArray`